# Specflow 2.0.0 What is the alternative to using ScenarioContext.Current?

Tags: specflow

I have upgraded to Specflow 2.0.0. with NUnit 3 (also tried with XUnit) and I want to be able to execute test cases in parallel in an attempt to reduce the elapsed time it takes to run the tests.

On attempting to execute the tests in parallel an error is returned stating that I cannot use FeatureContext.Current and ScenarioContext.Current.

The tests use these to extract the names of the feature and scenario for the additional logging.

The tests also use the tags to be able to control the tests.

For Example:
I am aware that it is possible to put the tags in the attributes

```
[Binding]
public class SpecFlowHooks
{
    public ScenarioContext context;

    public SpecFlowHooks(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        context = scenarioContext;
    }

    [BeforeScenario("SpecialCase")]
    public void BeforeScenario_SpecialCase() {
        do some stuff
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void BeforeScenario() {
        do different stuff
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that BeforeScenario always runs.  I do not want it to run if the tag "SpecialCase"  is not present as the application will not be in the correct state.  I therefore extract the tags and do something different if the tag "SpecialCase" is present.

How can I find the list of tags without using

```
List<String> tags = ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative for parallel execution is to allow the dependency injection system which specflow uses to provide you with the `ScenarioContext` instance. To do that have your steps class accept an instance of the `ScenarioContext` and store it in a field:

```
[Binding]
public class StepsWithScenarioContext
{
    private readonly ScenarioContext scenarioContext;

    public StepsWithScenarioContext(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        if (scenarioContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("scenarioContext");
        this.scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
    }

    [Given(@"I put something into the context")]
    public void GivenIPutSomethingIntoTheContext()
    {
        scenarioContext.Set("test-value", "test-key");
    }
}
```

A fuller explanation of how to use parallel execution can be found [here](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Parallel-Execution/)

A similar approach needs to be taken to get the tags. Again add a constructor which takes a `ScenarioContext` to your class which holds your `[BeforeScenario]` method, and save the `ScenarioContext` in a field and use this filed instead of the `ScenarioContext.Current`

Comment: Thank you Sam,  I have added a constructor public SpecFlowHooks (ScenarioContext scenarioContext) { _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;} to the class SpecFlowHooks which is the class that contains [BeforeScenario] but it is never called.  That was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: Sorry, no.  It would be great if it did as then I can call it from the class which is used to 'store' and 'recall' all of the data that is required for later on in the tests.  Enter data in the 'When' step with a table with all the data, store it using ScenarioContext and then in the 'Then' step just recall it for checking without having to enter all the data again in the story.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your `SpecFlowHooks` class, as this should work fine

Comment: Done.  When a breakpoint is put in the context = scenarioContext line it is never executed.  It does get executed when it is out in a class with [Given], [When] and [Then] but it will be a lot of work to be able to put this in all the classes as it is a fairly mature application.

Comment: and do you `[BeforeScenario]` hooks get executed? ie can you put a breakpoint in those and see it get hit?

Comment: Yes, the BeforeScenario does get executed as, among other things, Selenium.Start() is located in that method.

Comment: if your before scenario is executed, then the class must be constructed, so you must also have another public constructor with no parameters in this class. You should remove all constructors APART from the  one with the `ScenarioContext`

Comment: There are no other constructors in the class.